# Using $.each to call function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am I missing here? I need the click callback to call the `paginate.something.apply(paginate)` depending on if it's previous or next.

```
prevOrNext = ["previous", "next"],
    pageSet = {
        1: function(){
            paginate.previousPage.apply(paginate)
        },
        2: function(){
            paginate.nextPage.apply(paginate)
        }
    };

$.each(prevOrNext, function(n, v) {
    list[index++] = createLi(v).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        pageSet[n];
    });
});
```

Comment: `paginate[v + "Page"].apply(paginate);`?

Comment: That's it! Put it in an answer when you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a variable string to access a property, you can use the square bracket syntax:

```
var f = paginate[v + "Page"].apply(paginate);
```

Invoking a function involves appending parentheses containing a comma separated list of arguments, but it's obvious you know this from your code.

Comment: Thanks, I really needed a fresh pair of eyes to this.

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually calling the function. You probably meant to do this:

```
pageSet[n]();
```